# For Loop With C# Code Behind Method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, for-loop

When I debug in code behind It let me to go inside "Test" method only one time, not three times, why ? I see that I have javascript "for loop" which should go three times inside C# "Test" method. But it goes only one time, is this normal ? I want to go through "Test" method three times as I said in javascript "for loop". Where is the problem ?

aspx code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            console.log("active");
            var a = '<%= this.Test() %>';
        }
    });
</script>
```

C# code behind:

```
    public string Test()
    {
        int a = 1;
        return "active";
    }
```

Comment: What are you basing the "only 1 time" on?  Cause it looks like it'll run 3 times, but `a` will always be `1`.

Answer (score 8):

`this.Test()` is not being called in your `for` loop in javascript.  It is being called server-side to evaluate it.

Look at it this way.  Your javascript really says the following after rendering:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            console.log("active");
            var a = 'active';
        }
    });
</script>
```

The reason for this is in the way ASP.NET works.  It takes your xhtml and server-side code and renders html to spit back to the client.  The client then has a chance to execute any of its code.  Javascript is executed client-side.

Answer (score 4):

You are writing the result of the `Test` function as a string into the javascript, which will then execute once the browser loads the page.

If you want to run `Test` 3 times from the page itself, you'll want to look into one of the various Ajax libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The code only executes once in all cases. The for loop on the JavaScript will not execute the c# 3 times. Instead, the page is output only once as the `<%= this.Test() %>` is an output block that is interpreted a single time on the server. Your script clientside is then interpreted.